# count occurences of distinct elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

```
list = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7}
```

My actual list has around 4000 points.
I want to display the number of occurrences of each element.

I want to get a list like : `{0, 4}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}, {7, 2}`

0 occurs 4 times, 2 occurs 3 times and so on.

Comment: [`Tally`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html)